# How to fix Hebrew Mojibake in old files

Tags: encoding, unicode, hebrew

I have a set of plain text files with a mix of hebrew and english. These files are from the late 90s to early 2000s and were apparently written in NisusWriter.

When I open the text files the english lines render correctly but the hebrew lines are jumbled up mojibake like this:

```
 Â∆˙ŸÙœÏ∆À˙ÀÌ†††ÂŸ‰À÷Õ·†††‡Œ˙†††‰ÀÚ⁄·«„À‰††††
```

I wrote a loop to run iconv with every encoding it supports but none of the outputs were fixed

Running hexdump -C on the first 3 lines (one english, one jumbled hebrew, and one transliteration in latin characters) gave the following. It seems the jumbled hebrew is written as just . chars

```
00000010  50 2e 20 31 31 30 20 20  2d 20 41 56 4f 44 41 48  |P. 110  - AVODAH|
00000020  0d 0d 20 f8 d9 f6 cd e4  a0 ac a0 a0 a0 e9 d9 e9  |.. .............|
00000030  cb a0 a0 a0 e0 db ec dd  e4 cd d8 e9 f0 e5 c6 a0  |................|
00000040  ac a0 a0 a0 e1 c6 d9 f2  cc ee c6 d9 ea cb a0 a0  |................|
00000050  a0 e9 cf f9 dd d9 f8 cb  e0 cd ec a0 ac 0d 0d 52  |...............R|
00000060  65 2d 74 7a 65 68 d5 2c  20 20 20 20 41 64 6f 6e  |e-tzeh.,    Adon|
00000070  61 69 20 20 20 20 20 20  45 2d 6c 6f 2d 68 65 69  |ai      E-lo-hei|
00000080  d5 2d 6e 75 20 2c 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 62 65 2d  |.-nu ,       be-|
00000090  61 6d 2d 63 68 61 d5 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 79  |am-cha.        y|
000000a0  69 73 2d 72 61 2d 65 6c  d5 20 0d 62 65 20 70 6c  |is-ra-el. .be pl|
000000b0  65 61 73 65 64 2c 20 20  20 20 41 64 6f 6e 61 69  |eased,    Adonai|
```

Comment: Can you include a `hexdump -C` of the relevant part of those files?

Comment: @user1686, I added the hexdump -C output to the question. Never used that command before however

Comment: The right-hand column is just for quick visualization – it's the actual hex numbers that are useful, as they allow creating a file with the exact same bytes and experimenting on it. (Whereas just copy-pasting the mojibake itself rarely results in a decodable file.)

Comment: You need to find out the encoding used for your text files and make sure your editor, whichever is it, can handle it. Based on the dates you mention there is a risk they are not using UTF8 which is kind of defacto today, but in the past there were a plethora of "isolatin-" ones as well as other ones.

Comment: Unfortunately the files are not my own, so there's no way of determining the original encoding. Hence why I tried everything iconv could try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the end and thought I'd write it down in case others had similar problems.

I used a site I found to try every encoding under the sun until I got one where the hebrew rendered correctly, albeit with mysterious characters separator characters.

https://www.motobit.com/util/charset-codepage-conversion.asp

I was able to verify this by using the @user1686 suggestion to use the hex values from `hexdump`, and cross referencing in with the encoding table.

In the end it turned out the file was encoded as x-mac-hebrew